# Does anyone know why this mongo aggregation is no working?

Tags: python, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

```
db.COLL_CLIENTS.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "$and": [
                {
                    "SCountryCode": "CO"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "COLL_CCVIMPACTOS",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "join"
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$join"
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "join": {
                "$exists": 1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "impacto": {
                "$filter": {
                    "input": "$join.KImpacto",
                    "as": "item",
                    "cond": {
                        "$eq": [
                            "$$item.SMaterial",
                            "000000000000024174"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$impacto"
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "impacto": {
                "$exists": 1
            }
        }
    }
])
```

`My Client collection has 42,000 Documents`

`My Impact collection has 430,000 Documents`

Could not retrieve the next 50

Stacktrace:
|*/ java.lang.Exception: Could not retrieve the next 50
|*___/ Mongo Server error (MongoQueryException): Query failed with error code 2 and error message 'Error=2, Details='Response status code does not indicate success: BadRequest (400); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: abe32625-01c1-4327-8334-c6cfd5ea9cac; Reason: (Response status code does not indicate success: BadRequest (400); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: abe32625-01c1-4327-8334-c6cfd5ea9cac; Reason: (Response status code does not indicate success: BadRequest (400); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: abe32625-01c1-4327-8334-c6cfd5ea9cac; Reason: (Message: ��errors�ꀈseverity�Error�location�
�start